How do I write this formula for the second column to have the same sequence number if the value in the first column is the same?
I need the sequence in the second column to have the same value if the cell total in the first column is the same, there can be multiple totals the same. The sequence also needs to continue after the same number is accounted for.
I do not know where to start. I have sequenced the second column but do not know where to go from here.
Example
74  1
71  2
70  3
70  3
70  3
67  6
65  7
65  7
61  9




Col A
Col B




74
1


71
2


70
3


70
3


70
3


67
6


65
7


65
7


61
9




Welcome to Stack Overflow, please include (sample) data in Markdown Table, any attempts you made so far, desired outcome of the data (in markdown table as well). It is pretty unclear what you have and what you want, just from the little text you provided. Also, try to [edit] your tags, preferably with an excel version (we're assuming the latest version now), and in which area (excel-formula, vba, ...).

If I understood the question correctly, then sort data in your column A, add a starting number in B1, and apply the following formula in cell B2
=IF(A2=A1; B1; MAX($B$1:B1) + 1)

corrected fomula for O and P:
=IF(O1=O2; P1; P1 +COUNTIF($O$1:O1; O1))

Excel view


The sequence is not accounting for the duplicate numbers. example if the seq. is 1,2,3,3, then the next number would be 5,6,6, and then 8.

@garyFontaine just correct formula like this: =IF(A2=A1, B1, MAX($B$1:B1) + COUNTIF($A$1:A1, A2))

I oppoligize for wasting your time, I am trying to get the formula to create the sequence in column P from the data in column O, this is trying to read the seq. that isnt there. column O is 74,
71,
70,
70,
67,
65,
65,
64,
61,
60,
60,
60,
60,
59,
58,

The sequence also needs to start with 1 and not 0

@garyFontaine no problem. for O and P use this one: =IF(O1=O2; P1; P1 +COUNTIF($O$1:O1; O1)) i.sstatic.net/0Z18vzCY.png

If it will always be the case that, as in your example, your data is sorted descending, then you can simply use the RANK.EQ function:
P1: =RANK.EQ(O1:O9,O1:O9)



That worked, Thank you so much

@garyFontaine Glad to help. Please mark one of the answers that works as "Accepted". See What should I do when someone answers my question.
